# Cannot access ref from React context

Tags: reactjs

For some reason, with React 18 and Typescript 5.x, I cannot seem to access the properties of a ref that is most definitely set and defined through a context wrapper. I have something like this:

Parent component with context

```
interface MyContextValues {
  ref: LegacyRef<ExternalApi>
} 

export const MyComponentContext = createContext<MyContextValues>({ref:null})

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef<ExternalThing | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current); // ok!
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <MyComponent.Provider> value={{ref}}
      <SomeComponent ref={ref}/>
    </MyComponent.Provider>);
}

export const useMyComponentContext<MyContextValues>(MyContext);
```

Child component

```
export const MyChildComponent = () => {
  const { ref } = useMyComponentContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Property 'current' does not exist on type 'string | ((instance: ExternalThing | null) => void) | RefObject<ExternalThing >'.
    // Property 'current' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

    console.log(ref.current);

    // But it actually logs out fine to the expected value... 
  }, [ref]);
  return <div></div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `React.RefObject` instead of `React.LegacyRef`